# Problemas ao incluir library em projecto de qt

Tags: qt

Estou de momento a tentar **incluir a biblioteca rtmidi** num *projecto* de **qt** para **fazer binding em um sistema de interface gráfico que criei com mensagens Midi.**

**Adicionei a seguinte linha** ao meu projecto:

```
#include <RtMidi.h>
```

No ficheiro ***.pro,** *pode ler-se o seguinte*:

```
TEMPLATE = app

QT += qml quick
CONFIG += c++11

INCLUDEPATH += _files_3rdParty/rtmidi

SOURCES += src/main.cpp

LIBS += -L"_files_3rdParty/rtmidi" -lrtmidi

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    _files_3rdParty/rtmidi/doc/doxygen/samples/getting_started.cpp \
    _files_3rdParty/rtmidi/tests/cmidiin.cpp \
    _files_3rdParty/rtmidi/tests/midiclock.cpp \
    _files_3rdParty/rtmidi/tests/midiout.cpp \
    _files_3rdParty/rtmidi/tests/midiprobe.cpp \
    _files_3rdParty/rtmidi/tests/qmidiin.cpp \
    _files_3rdParty/rtmidi/tests/sysextest.cpp \
    _files_3rdParty/rtmidi/RtMidi.cpp \
    _files_3rdParty/rtmidi/rtmidi_c.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

DISTFILES += \
    _files_3rdParty/rtmidi/autogen.sh \
    _files_3rdParty/rtmidi/rtmidi-config.in \
    _files_3rdParty/rtmidi/msw/rtmidilib.vcproj \
    _files_3rdParty/rtmidi/doc/images/ccrma.gif \
    _files_3rdParty/rtmidi/doc/images/mcgill.gif \
    _files_3rdParty/rtmidi/doc/doxygen/footer.html \
    _files_3rdParty/rtmidi/doc/doxygen/header.html \
    _files_3rdParty/rtmidi/doc/doxygen/Doxyfile.in \
    _files_3rdParty/rtmidi/doc/doxygen/tutorial.txt \
    _files_3rdParty/rtmidi/doc/release.txt \
    _files_3rdParty/rtmidi/msw/rtmidilib.sln \
    _files_3rdParty/rtmidi/tests/cmidiin.dsp \
    _files_3rdParty/rtmidi/tests/midiout.dsp \
    _files_3rdParty/rtmidi/tests/midiprobe.dsp \
    _files_3rdParty/rtmidi/tests/qmidiin.dsp \
    _files_3rdParty/rtmidi/tests/RtMidi.dsw \
    _files_3rdParty/rtmidi/tests/sysextest.dsp \
    _files_3rdParty/rtmidi/rtmidi.pc.in \
    _files_3rdParty/rtmidi/README.md \
    _files_3rdParty/rtmidi/msw/readme

HEADERS += \
    _files_3rdParty/rtmidi/configure.ac \
    _files_3rdParty/rtmidi/RtMidi.h \
    _files_3rdParty/rtmidi/rtmidi_c.h
```

Estou com uma série de *warnings* e um erro que me diz que não existe regra para compilar o *src* do `main.o`

O que estou a fazer de errado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

acabei por **incluir o projecto como:**

```
#include <RtMidi.h>
```

fazendo **linking da biblioteca nos resources**

e **adicionando o seguinte código ao ficheiro *.pro**

```
TEMPLATE = app

QT += qml quick
CONFIG += c++11

INCLUDEPATH += _files_3rdParty/rtmidi/

SOURCES += main.cpp \

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

DISTFILES += \

HEADERS += \
```